# Must match multiple values

Tags: elasticsearch

I have a query that works fine when I need the property of a document
to match just one value.

However I also need to be able to search with must with two values.

So if a banana has id 1 and a lemon has id 2 and I search for yellow
I will get both if I have 1 and 2 in the must clause.
But if i have just 1 I will only get the banana.

```
{
  "from": 0, 
  "size": 20,
  "query": {
  "bool": {
    "should": [
      { "match": 
        { "fruit.color":  "yellow" }}
    ],
    "must" : [ 
      { "match": { "fruit.id" : "1" } }
    ]
  }
 } 
}
```

I haven´t found a way to search with two values with must.
is that possible?

Comment: what if i have 10 different query params from the api to be used in search query and some of the query params have values, some of them may not. in general all the 10 different query params will behave randomly. should i construct "if.. elif" construct to check if value exists or not to perform search. is there any better way.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

If the document "must" be returned only if the id is 1 or 2, that sounds like another `should` clause. If I'm understanding your question properly, you want documents with either id 1 OR id 2. Additionally, if the color is yellow, give it a higher score.

Here's one way you might achieve what you're looking for:

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "should": {
        "match": {
          "fruit.color": "yellow"
        }
      },
      "must": {
        "bool": {
          "should": [
            {
              "match": {
                "fruit.id": "1"
              }
            },
            {
              "match": {
                "fruit.id": "2"
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Here I put the two `match` queries in the `should` clause of a separate bool query. This achieves the OR behavior you are looking for.

Have another look at the [Bool Query documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-bool-query.html) and take note of the nuances of `should`. It behaves differently by default depending on whether or not there is a sibling `must` clause and whether or not the bool query is being executed in *filter context*.

Another key option that is adjustable and can help you achieve your expected results is the `minimum_should_match` parameter. [Have a look at this documentation page](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-minimum-should-match.html).

Comment: @dontberude Glad I could help. :)  If you get a chance, consider accepting my answer so that other StackOverflow users with a similar issue might benefit from it as well.

Comment: Thanks man! been searching for a way of achieving multiple `must` on the same field.

Comment: Thanks a lot for this! I'd spent such a long time trying to include a `should` on the same level as a `must` and failing.

Comment: it's better to use `term` for matching ids, also use `terms` to match it with an array of ids

Answer (score 36):

Instead of a match query, you could simply try the `terms` query for `OR`ing between multiple terms.

Match queries are generally used for `analyzed` fields. For exact matching, you should use `term queries`

```
{
  "from": 0, 
  "size": 20,
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "should": [
        { "match": { "fruit.color": "yellow" } }
      ],
      "must" : [ 
        { "terms": { "fruit.id": ["1","2"] } }
      ]
    }
  } 
}
```

Comment: Depends on the mapping, if set up the right way, it works, otherwise no results will be returned.

Comment: you might be analysed the field as a text. need to analyse it as a keyword.

Comment: Note that this OK if you just want to filter with the given terms, but it might ruin your scoring if you need to score based on field relevance.  That's because `terms`  internally uses a `constant_score` query for whatever reason

Answer (score 10):

term or terms query is the perfect way to fetch the exact `text` or `id`, using match query result in search inside the id or text

Ex: 
id = '4'
id = '44'

Search using match query with id = 4 return both 4 & 44 since it matches 4 in both. This is where terms query come into play.
same search using terms query will return 4 only.

So the accepted is absolutely wrong. Use the @Rahul answer. Just one more thing you need to do, Instead of text you need to analyse the field as a keyword

**Example for indexing a field both as a text and keyword *(mapping is for flat level for nested change it accordingly)*.**

```
{
    "index_patterns": [ "test" ],
    "mappings": {
        "kb_mapping_doc": {
            "_source": {
                "enabled": true
            },
            "properties": {
                "id": {
                    "type": "text",
                    "fields": {
                        "keyword": {
                            "type": "keyword"
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

using @Rahul's answer doesn't worked because you might be analysed as a text.

- id - access a text field
- id.keyword - access a keyword field

it would be

```
{
    "from": 0,
    "size": 20,
    "query": {
        "bool": {
            "should": [{
                "match": {
                    "color": "yellow"
                }
            }],
            "must": [{
                "terms": {
                    "id.keyword": ["1", "2"]
                }
            }]
        }
    }
}
```

So I would say accepted answer will return falsy results Please use @Rahul's answer with the corresponding mapping.